# Clicking on the image in the GridView do not display ListView

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have created a GridView in my activity but when I am clicking on the image in the GridView it should show the screen whose intent I have given in which I am displaying List of some items but I am not getting the ListView displayed but all other Logcat statements inside that class is running

The code of GridView is

GridLayoutActivity.java

```
public class GridLayoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_content);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new GalleryAdapter(this));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id)
            {


                    Toast.makeText(GridLayoutActivity.this, "" + position,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Hindi_SongsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);




                /*if(position==1)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), English_SongsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if(position==2)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Melody_SongsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }*/

            }
        });



    }
}
```

This is the Adapter Code for GridView

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.bollywood1, R.drawable.hollywood1,
            R.drawable.melody

    };

    // Constructor
    public GalleryAdapter(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

This is my xml code for GridView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/my_subtle_pattern"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

Code for the ListView is

```
public class Hindi_SongsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private ListView mlistview;
    private Firebase mRef;
    private ArrayList<String> titles=new ArrayList<String>();
    private String TAG=English_SongsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hindi_songs_list);
        mlistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hindi_songs);

   DatabaseReference hindi= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vikas").child("Music").child("Hindi");
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,titles);
        mlistview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

       hindi.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                for(DataSnapshot hindi_songs: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    for (DataSnapshot hindi_songs_children : hindi_songs.getChildren())
                    {
                        if (hindi_songs_children.getKey().equals("title"))
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG, "run");
                            String value = hindi_songs_children.getValue().toString();
                            titles.add(value);
                        }

                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG,"titles"+titles.size());
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {


            }
        });
        mlistview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
}
```

And the xml listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/hindi_songs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/my_subtle_pattern"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the logcat which I am getting when I am clicking on the image in the GridView

05-01 20:54:53.229 27182-27247/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-01 20:54:53.330 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base D/FA: Connected to remote service
05-01 20:54:53.330 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
05-01 20:54:58.373 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
05-01 20:55:00.022 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 6863
05-01 20:55:00.023 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Using measurement service
05-01 20:55:00.023 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Connecting to remote service
05-01 20:55:00.027 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Activity paused, time: 94963992
05-01 20:55:00.037 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
05-01 20:55:00.050 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=6863, _sc=GridLayoutActivity, _si=5934656916561625555}]
05-01 20:55:00.090 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Using measurement service
05-01 20:55:00.090 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
05-01 20:55:00.137 27182-27182/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: onActivityCreated
05-01 20:55:00.266 27182-27182/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:5
05-01 20:55:00.266 27182-27182/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 5
05-01 20:55:00.289 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Using measurement service
05-01 20:55:00.289 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
05-01 20:55:00.289 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 94964259
05-01 20:55:00.349 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base D/FA: Connected to remote service
05-01 20:55:00.349 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 3
05-01 20:55:00.441 27182-27247/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x5574c703d0 (GridView) with handle 0x5574c7e860
05-01 20:55:05.445 27182-27234/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
05-01 20:55:07.273 27182-27182/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base D/English_SongsActivity: run
05-01 20:55:07.274 27182-27182/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base D/English_SongsActivity: run
05-01 20:55:07.274 27182-27182/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base D/English_SongsActivity: run
05-01 20:55:07.274 27182-27182/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base D/English_SongsActivity: run
05-01 20:55:07.274 27182-27182/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base D/English_SongsActivity: run
05-01 20:55:07.274 27182-27182/com.dekhoapp.android.app.base D/English_SongsActivity: titles5

Comment: So you mean to say that your 'Hindi_SongsActivity.class' activity is getiing launched where you have a ListView. But you cannot see the ListView there ???

Comment: Yes that is the thing what is happening

Comment: and if I am running seperately that ListView Activity so it is displaying the list

Comment: ok. Please post the code for the ListView adapter and teh code where you are setting the ListView adapter in your activity. let me have a look where its going wrong

Comment: I have updated my code have a look

Comment: Log.d(TAG,"titles"+titles.size()); what is this value ??

Comment: this is value of  total number of items in the form of arraylist  that is to be displayed in the listviewfetched from Firebase database

Comment: okie. I got that. whats titles.size() ?? See the thing is that what I feel is your ListView item count is 0, thats why you are not able to see it. We just need to see where its becoming 0

Comment: but in the logcat in the last line you can see the size is 5